# Replace two or more spaces within a text file with a ;

Tags: unix, sed, awk

File1:

```
hello      world
foo   bar
a  word with a space
```

I need to replace all white spaces which are two or more in length with a semi-colon(;).

Result:

File2:

```
hello;world
foo;bar
a;word with a space
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/  \+/;/g' File1 > File2
```

Comment: Sweet! Saved me tonnes of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="  +"}{$1=$1}1' OFS=";" file
hello;world
foo;bar
a;word with a space

$ awk '{gsub(/  +/,";")}1' file
hello;world
foo;bar
a;word with a space
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
sed -e 's/  */;/g' file
```

Comment: Removed spaces of one length as well DX.